# Can I "unregister" a module from AngularJS 1.2?

Tags: angularjs

Can I "unregister" a module from AngularJS 1.2?

I am adding a module to a project and wish to unregister it later.

Comment: Modules are loaded with the main module, because you are using It somewhere at your application, meaning that you have a strong dependency on this loaded module. If you take of just this module you will break down every reference for this at your application and everything else will stop work. If this module works stand alone, you can load It dynamically using RequireJS, without take everything else to the ground

Comment: WHat is the higher level issue for wanting to do this?

Comment: I thought I could register a module with angular after bootstrap, but this is not the case AFAICT.